# Eclipse enter shortcut jumps too far

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new to Eclipse and so far really like shortcuts. However, when I am typing a for loop and use something like .size(), pressing enter sends me outside of the loop conditions.

The | marks where my cursor is

```
//Pressing enter with my cursor here
for (int i = 0; i < example.size(|))

//sends the cursor here
for (int i = 0; i < example.size())|
```

When I only want it to advance past the first round bracket. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Press the right arrow key twice.

Comment: Well actually pressing the right arrow key twice puts my in the exact same spot. Pressing it once put it where I want, but as long as the enter shortcut exists I would prefer to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using TAB instead? I'm a Mac guy and my Eclipse accepts tabs.

Also you must be very sure to use the code hints that Eclipse lists for you in order to use such features.